# Django: avoid race condition for field which value based on aggregation

Tags: django, race-condition

There is example model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to set `version` field value based on max version of instances with same name. To do this I override `save` method:

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       max_version = MyModel.objects \
           .filter(name=self.name) \
           .aggregate(max_version=Max('version'))['max_version'] or 0
       self.version = max_version + 1
       super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How to avoid race condition here?

**Edit:** version must be unique (between instances with same name) but order is not too important.

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution of this problem? I faced this one some time ago, and I have to use Redis Locks to control execution flow and prevent race conditions, but it does not seem to be a good practice...

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple atomic [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#module-django.db.transaction) should solve your problem.

```
from django.db import transaction


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        max_version = MyModel.objects \
           .filter(name=self.name) \
           .aggregate(max_version=Max('version'))['max_version'] or 0
        self.version = max_version + 1
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Though out of the scope of the actual question, you might want to update the `version` field only while creating the record (saving for the first time). You can do that by verifying that the `pk` is `None` like this.

```
from django.db import transaction


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        with transaction.atomic():
            max_version = MyModel.objects \
               .filter(name=self.name) \
               .aggregate(max_version=Max('version'))['max_version'] or 0
            self.version = max_version + 1
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    else:
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It looks like simple and clear solution, but.. It does not work:) 
Several transactions can start-read-commit almost simultaneously and as a result, we'll get several records with one version.

Comment: I see what you mean. Atomic transactions do not prevent other transactions from reading the rows. 
Django also has [`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) which can guarantee that the rows in use are locked, preventing other transactions from reading them. This should be supported on most databases.
While this works, I would simply add a unique constraint on the two columns and use the above code that guarantees atomicity.